# How do we find how many values for a Smooth square root?

Tags: project-euler

this question is from the Eulers project
The positive integer is called square root smooth if all of the prime factors it has are less than its square root.
**Including the number 1, there are 29 square rooot smooth numbers not exceeding 100.**

this is what I have so far. but i don't understand how to check for each value. **How can I prove in Mathematica that there are exactly  29 square root numbers that don't exceed 100?**

```
 g = (n^(1/2)) /. n -> Range[1, 100];
 j = Simplify[g]
 k = Primes[n^(1/2)) /. n -> Range[1, 100], g <= n^(1/2))]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Select`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html)

```
srs = Select[Range[100], 
  And @@ Thread[FactorInteger[#][[All, 1]] < Sqrt[#]] &]

{8, 12, 16, 18, 24, 27, 30, 32, 36, 40, 45, 48, 50, 54, 56, 60, 63, 64, 70, \
72, 75, 80, 81, 84, 90, 96, 98, 100}

Length@srs

(* 28 *)
```

With `1` the count is `29`